# (node.js) defining subdomains without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, localhost, subdomain

Can you explain me how to create a subdomain for my server (explicitly without Express) ?

Why if I do the following, the request does not show me the subdomains ?

```
http = require("http");

server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.url); //should prints "/" (because a subdomain should be considered like a new website)
   console.log(req.headers.host); //should prints "sub.localhost"       
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end("Ok");
}).listen(80);
```

Now, if I navigate to http://sub.localhost/ chrome says "This webpage is not available" and from the node.js console does not prints nothing, why ?

Is there a specific procedure to set up a subdomain in order to be accessible from Node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `sub.localhost` set (e.g. `127.0.0.1 sub.localhost`) in your OS `hosts` file, otherwise it probably does not know how to resolve that hostname.

On Windows the `hosts` file is typically `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

On all other platforms the `hosts` file is typically `/etc/hosts`.